# ROWLEX: Classes with the same property names not working:ROWLEX

Tags: rowlex

I have some complex classes which many of then have a class as a property. I have tried to mark up the class file with th ROWLEX attribute markers but when more than one class has the same property name, the Rowlex extractor gives an error.

I have produced a very simple set of classes Leg, Animal, Table. Both Table & Animal have Legs which is an Array of Leg....

The error message is:http://nc3a.nato.int/10/16/ZooOntology#Legs is assigned to more than one type.

Imports NC3A.SI.Rowlex

http://nc3a.nato.int/10/16/ZooOntology")>

Namespace Namespace1

```
<RdfSerializable(Ontology:="http://nc3a.nato.int/10/16/ZooOntology", HasResourceUri:=False)> _
Public Class Leg

End Class

<RdfSerializable(Ontology:="http://nc3a.nato.int/10/16/ZooOntology", HasResourceUri:=False)> _
  Public Class House
    <RdfProperty(False)> _
        Public readonly Property Legs() As Leg()
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
End Class


<RdfSerializable(Ontology:="http://nc3a.nato.int/10/16/ZooOntology", HasResourceUri:=False)> _
    Public Class Table
    <RdfProperty(False)> _
    Public ReadOnly Property Legs() As Leg()
        Get
            Return Nothing
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

ROWLEX2.1 solves the issue, you may download it from http://rowlex.nc3a.nato.int. For more detailed explanation and sample code, please look at [this similar StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243410/how-to-define-a-property-with-same-name-on-two-different-types-in-rowlex).